# Preload WebSite

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am using the iPhone simulator that is part of the SDK to test a jQuery Mobile website.  I have the startup of the simulator scripted but once the simulator is up and running, I still have to click on Safari/enter the website URL.  Is there a way to preload Safari/website URL through the shell script?

Comment: By the way, for those looking for the startup command that can be scripted, I am using: open -n /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following... Once you open your webpage via mobile safari, look at the bottom tool bar where you see a set of icons. Click on the centre one "Share" and you get a list of options. Select "Add to home screen" and give it a name when prompted. Now, you will have this page added to the home screen and you can simply open this with a click.